# Please help me with this sentence: 手術台から...噛みました

Tags: translation, song-lyrics, particle-から

I'm trying to translate this song, and there is a sentence I really don't understand:

> 手術台から･･･噛みました

Here's the line in context, if that helps anyone:

> 金持ちあいつの恋煩い (the lovesickness of the rich guy)
>   手術台から･･･噛みました (from the operating table, he chews?)
>   口から這い出た愛してる (from his mouth, love creeps out)

I think (maybe) that that line means something like he's chewing his fingernails or grinding his teeth, like he's nervous, but it doesn't really say anything like that directly.

Anyways, I'm really confused!

Comment: Where's the tag for "bizarre"?  :)

Answer (score 4):

First, here are the whole lyrics for anyone curious.

https://www5.atwiki.jp/hmiku/pages/25195.html

Having read the whole song, I think I have an answer here.  The whole lyrics are just full of plays on words, unusually twisted humor and all the other nonsense by the "normal" song lyric standards.

To me, 「噛{か}む」 here is used for its other "colloquial" meaning "**to fluff a line**" rather than for its "dictionary" meaning of "to bite, chew".

The ***ellipsis*** used in the line would strongly suggest the stumbling.  Besides, I just do not see what is there to bite or chew.

"**On the operating table ... oops, I fluffed**." would be my take.

This would explain the polite verb form 「噛みました」 which would imply an apology as well as the ellipsis I mentioned above.

Comment: From what I took of the song, it seemed to me that the "rich guy" was always falling in love with people who were hurt, which is why I thought that perhaps from the sidelines, he was watching the operation. Would you perhaps think that maybe "oops, I fluffed" should be "oops, they fluffed?" As in, he saw the doctors make a mistake? That would fit more with my interpretation of the song; but maybe my interpretation is wrong.   Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I'll add to l'électeur's answer. As mentioned in the answer, it means "to fluff a line". It cannot be interpreted as any other type of mistake outside of verbally messing up a line. When I see an unfinished line, followed by 噛{か}んだ or 噛{か}みました in a script (or in this case, a song) my initial instinct is that the speaker has messed up the unfinished line. And I see that 手術台{しゅじゅつだい} is there, and I know that 手術{しゅじゅつ} is a word that is often fluffed. There's even a tongue-twister for that.

> 魔術師{まじゅつし}手術中｛しゅじゅつちゅう｝

I have searched an listened to the song, found [here](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm20657613), and that has confirmed my belief. The singer fluffs the pronunciation, saying しゅじゅちゅだい instead.

Comment: That does make more sense! I looked up しゅじゅちゅだい and I found that is a common mispronunciation of 手術. I suppose that in the song, he must have messed up the word because he was nervous. Thank you for your help!