# Translation of an odd line: お喋り顔事娘と　水槽の GID

Tags: translation, words

So I was translating this song (full lyrics: https://www5.atwiki.jp/hmiku/pages/25196.html) and I ran across this line which I'm very confused about.

> お喋り顔事娘と　水槽の GID
>   誤解を捕まえて　魚を釣るの

My attempted translation would be, "A girl who pretends to be chatty and the GID of a water tank; seizing on the misunderstanding, and hooking the fish."

My biggest problem is お喋り顔事娘 - the translation above is the best me and some of my friends could get out of it when we tried to figure it out, but considering 誤解を捕まえて and the fact that when I was translating a different song by this producer, there was some wordplay having to do with misspeaking ([Please help me with this sentence: 手術台から...噛みました](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43525/please-help-me-with-this-sentence-%E6%89%8B%E8%A1%93%E5%8F%B0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-%E5%99%9B%E3%81%BF%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F)), I'm wondering if it's the same situation here, though after research I can't think of what it might be or what's happening. The song is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dyAlYhicXk and that part is at 1:55.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

お喋り is 'chat', but 顔事娘と absolutely makes no sense if we read this in a normal way. I doubt the "literal" translation can be any better than "face matter daughter and". If this is a pun, which is likely, the closest phrase that makes some sense is お喋りかお仕事 ("chat or work"). Judging from the rest of the lyrics, perhaps 事 and 娘 were chosen almost arbitrarily.

誤解を捕まえて魚を釣る is probably also a pun for [ゴカイ](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%B4%E3%82%AB%E3%82%A4%E9%A1%9E)を捕まえて魚を釣る. ゴカイ is a kind of fishing bait. Apparently 誤解 was chosen simply because it sounded similar, and I doubt there is a deep meaning in "capturing the misunderstanding".

Comment: Okay, thank you! It does sound like お喋りかお仕事 in the song. Do you have any idea what GID could mean in this context? I was hoping it would be clear after knowing what お喋り顔事娘 is supposed to mean, but apparently not. Is GID an expression you've heard used in Japanese before? As a native English speaker, nothing is coming to mind, so I was wondering if this was more commonly used in Japanese.